# What is the relationship between domain models and view models? Do they need to be separate? (Does using EF complicate this?)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

So my programming background is very self-taught and sporadic.  I am working on an MVC4 project and am trying to focus on best practices rather than just functionality.

The general sense of the project is a report generator.  So I am trying to understand what exactly Domain Model vs View Model are, and how they related to the models used for CodeFirst Entity Framework.  Any tips are appreciated.

From my understanding, let's say my Report object has multiple properties, but for the view I only want a user to be able to edit certain properties, then the ViewModel would be something that maps between the Report object and the user input?

Comment: Not a real question, see: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: @SpikeX - Rephrased the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you've got the right idea.  A `ViewModel` is the View representation of the domain entity.  This can be applied to both data coming in and data going out of the model.

But, the extra layer (and mappings) also increase complexity of the code.  You now need a view model class, a mapper class, and a domain entity (EF).  So, if you can build what you need without this extra layer, then keep it simple.  Domain models and domain modeling should only be used for a business domain that is significantly complex.

Comment: So naturally I would need a Report class in this case.  However, is it safe to say I can end up with a DomainModel, ViewModel, and DomainEntity all called Report?  i.e. the Report class will have loads of fields for different parts of the report.  The ViewModel will have only the information that the user can directly do anything with, and the entity would have the information that gets put in the database.

Comment: Yes, that is reasonable.  The general idea is to make your view as simple as possible and to protect your domain from view concerns.

Comment: As for naming, I have seen a lot of different opinions...`Report`, and `ReportViewModel` usually are fine. However, you might want to target the view model naming to the action.  Like `ReportSortCommand` etc.

Comment: Thanks!  One thing that is bugging me is I have several subclasses that are used by Report.  i.e. there is an IList<ReportAssessmentSection> Sections; property in the class.  I found that in order to use EF, I essentially made ReportAssessmentSection serializable and then serialized the IList<ReportAssessmentSection> into a string property of Report.  This seems like a bad idea, but I could not find another way to get this to work with EF.  Does this needlessly complicate the models?

Comment: Sounds like a further question that others could benefit from :)  I'm guessing the `Section` part has to do with the view and the `ReportAssessment` part belongs to the model.

Comment: @pendraggon87  That does sound worthy of a question unto itself.  I'm not clear on what you're asking, but a guess would be that you have a case where there is a relationship that should be represented in your database, perhaps using a many-to-many, such that you would no longer need to serialize that to a string.

Answer (score 2):

Yes your understanding is correct.

View model is data object used by your view. It contains properties necessary either for showing some data to user or collecting data from user. Those properties doesn't necessarily be only data. For example you can have some properties used to control if any field in the input form will be enabled or disabled.

Domain model on the other hand is object used for your logic and persistence. Again it doesn't necessarily contain only persisted properties. There can be other properties computed from persisted properties and there can be also methods working on top of properties.

In some very simple scenarios view model and domain model can be represented by the same object.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I've seen in a few examples, what I've used for the last couple years and feel comfortable with, and was also the pattern already in use by a preexisting MVC team when I came into my most recent job.

Basically entity framework, or whatever ORM your using, will have Entity classes.  These are either simple POCO's or something heavier with some ORM's.  The goal is for the relationships between entities to closely resemble reality, and as such they are in a way your "Domain models".  Either way, you will often find that you're view needs to either flatten properties from child/parent objects, or as you mentioned, only display certain fields.

Often times you will also need additional fields on the view model. For example, the options for a dropdown list, as these aren't part of the entity(only the foreign key that indicates which item is selected is in the entity, but not the list of items from which the user can select).

So unless your view is simple enough to be able to use the @model of your EF entity, often times you may need a ViewModel(VM) class.  Some people have a different VM for each view.  I personally try to reuse my VMs.  Usually a PersonSummaryViewModel which is just a few fields good for things like select lists or indexes where space is limited and I will only display important fields, and a PersonViewModel which are all the fields from the entity, as well as fields for items for dropdown lists(but when used on a readonly page those are simply left null).

Personally I like to name things PersonVM and PersonSummaryVM but others prefer more verbose naming of PersonViewModel.  EF will give your entities names like Person, but I've seen other ORM frameworks suffix all of the classes with Entity so you have PersonEntity.  I've come to be fond of the Entity suffix personally.

If your database is well designed, it is likely that your entity classes are pretty close to what some would consider your domain model.

We have classes that expose static methods which we call to retrieve data.  The controllers have little to no database code in them, and instead all of that are in static methods like PersonModelFactory.GetList(), PersonModelFactory.GetSingle(int id), .Save(PersonVM person) which are responsible for querying the database, and populating the data from the entities into the view models, and then returning a view model.  These methods also perform certain validation(beyond what basic things you can do with data annotations on your view models), and other business logic IF it is something that should occur in tandem with whatever database modification is occurring.  There's more to the implementation details involving interfaces and generic parameters that are aimed at making these methods very reusable but it is a little complicated for the scope of this post.  We've actually successfully reused these classes from both web forms and MVC, so they've proved there re-usability.  Some people wouldn't like the fact the DB access, mapping, and business logic/validation occurs in the same layer, but since the DB modification shouldn't occur unless validation passes, we felt it was important for these things to be atomic and mutually dependent.

It is probably more common for people to use the "repository pattern" for database access layer with MVC, and there are even scaffolding for MVC to generate these classes for you.  However, these generally won't handle mapping or business logic.

Either way, the main goal is reuse and minimizing the clutter in your controller actions.  Before adopting the factor pattern I mentioned, I found my controllers becoming cluttered.  I saw opportunities for code to be reused between actions, and thus I was creating private methods in the controller.  I really like the factory pattern the team I'm on now uses alot more.

You will definitely find many variations of how people use view models and repositories.

I cannot recall having seen any articles or examples that speak specifically about "domain models" in the context of MVC.  IMO domain modelling is part of the requirements gathering process, and then the design of the database/entity framework will reflect the results of those findings. Given limitations of time/resources/complexity you may simplify the domain model.  There are frameworks that deal with things like domain languages and what not, I don't think that kind of thing is very common.

Before there were ORMs, there were people doing alot of mapping manually between the database layer(consisting of command objects running SQL), into "business objects" which were often POCOs, basically what you have as EF entities, but sometimes they had some business validation/logic incorporated somehow.  Now I don't hear people talk about "business objects" hardly ever because the purpose that layer served has mostly been replaced with EF, and the business logic is either in controller actions or in some other service layer.

Over the years, one thing is certain, what "view model", "business model", "entity", and "domain model" mean to different people will vary.